# phone-to-phone data connection

Tags: android, connection

I am a freelance systems administrator and architech. I have two small simple android apps that communicate with each other... One is a "server" that receives commands and the other is a "client" that sends the commands... Example: the client connects to the servers IP:Port and sends: "PC1 WAKEUP" The server executes wake on lan for PC1. Or the client sends "PC1 ls -la" and i receive the file list on the client... It works in my local network with wifi and i have configured port forwarding to access the server (an old android phone always connected to my wifi) from my phone anywhere as long as both have internet connection... And this is my problem... My home internet connection has many down periods and breaks... GSM does not...

So i want to do the same using GSM, CDMA or a direct data connection using a data call. I want to establish a data connection between the two android phones. In a similar way to connecting two PC using modems. One dials the number, the other is waiting and picks up the call and they communicate...

I have been trying to find a way to do this and i even learnd a little about XMPP and google talk but it seams to be outdated... It seams to be possible by exchanging SMSs but is not as functional and can be very expensive (and slow) for long sets of commands... I have a number of equipments at home that i need to interact with... in a fast way... I am lost here... Is this even possible? I cant find a way to do this... Any help is welcome... Even if i am looking at this the wrong way... New ideas are also welcome...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If they're on the same wlan connection, you can do WifiDirect.  Or traditional networking.  If not-  writing a server to run on a mobile phone is next to impossible.  IPs change too frequently to keep DNS up to date, and cell networks are firewalled.  You're just not going to have any reliable way to connect to a phone without a central server of some sort.  You can try hacks like SMS, but remember that SMS is unreliable-  messages may be dropped, or delivered days later (I just lost my phone, when I got the new one a week later I got several days worth of SMS at once-  all of them with a timestamp of right now).  You need a central server.

Comment: Is there no way to use the internal modem to make dial-up connections? Thats what i has hoping for...

Comment: No. I suppose it would be technically possible for them to do it, but the bit rate would be less than an old school phone modem, and very inefficient. Telecoms don't want to do bad data over voice channels at a cost of 100x a normal data one

Comment: When you say i need a central server do you mean something like google's hangouts servers?
Because using mobile data ont the phones this migth be a possibility...
I have found some posts in forum about people trying to use GTalk and Hangouts servers for sending media and data...
They work on mobile data and, in theory,  would not be affected by breaks on my internet connection.